# Override string MIPS

Tags: mips

Have to copy the second string in the first, when the strings are the same size right but when the second is less complete with characters from the first in that space over. Follows the code. I am grateful if someone help.

```
.data  

string1:    .asciiz "Hello"  
string2:    .asciiz "Word"  
finalStr:   .space 256       # A 256 bytes buffer 
buffer:     .space 100

.text  


main:  

   la $s1, finalStr  
   la $s2, string1  
   la $s3, string2  


   copySecondString:  

       lb $t0, ($s3)                  # get character at address  
       beqz $t0, exit
       sb $t0, ($s2)                  # else store current character in the buffer  
       addi $s3, $s3, 1               # string1 pointer points a position forward  
       addi $s2, $s2, 1               # same for finalStr pointer  
       j copySecondString             # loop     

   exit:

       la $a0, string1  
       li $v0,4
       syscall

       li $v0, 10 
       syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not null terminating the string and hence it is bleeding over into the characters left over when the first string is longer than the second.

To fix this, move the check for null after the store instruction:

```
lb $t0, ($s3)                  # get character at address  
sb $t0, ($s2)                  # store current character in the buffer
beqz $t0, exit                 # exit if null
```

Comment: Thank you Konrad Lindenbach.